# Show Date in Other months as well as month and year menus in Jquery Calendar

Tags: jquery, calendar

I am trying to modify the Jquery calendar to show both month and year menus as well as Show Date in Other months.

The code to Show Date in Other months is:

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOtherMonths: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true
    });
  } );
  </script>
```

The code to Show month and yearis:

```
 <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
  } );
  </script>
```

When I try to combine both it doesnt work, is it a bug in the calendar that cannot be fixed?

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOtherMonths: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true

      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
  } );
  </script>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="///code.jquery.com/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( ".myDatepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOtherMonths: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true,
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
  } );
  </script>

 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker1" class="myDatepicker"></p>
 fsdfsdfsd
 
 sdf
 sdf
 sdf
 
 <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker2" class="myDatepicker"></p>
 
  fsdfsdfsd
 
 sdf
 sdf
 sdf
 <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker3" class="myDatepicker"></p>
```

[image][image]

I am trying to combine both.

Comment: [Works fine here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gH6ZsKx6XFFMvbZePExL?p=preview) combining both

Comment: @charlietfl doesnt work when there are muliple calendars <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker1"></p>

Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker2">

Comment: Modify demo to show it not working

Comment: @charlietfl that worked, with removing commas

Answer (score 0):

Changed the code to following and worked

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOtherMonths: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true,    
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
  } );
  </script>
```